# Name does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update a view using a gridview with edit and update buttons.  I am using some code from code projects and the code looks like this :

```
    private void BindData()

    {

        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [vw_GridviewSource] WHERE (([Annotation Date] = @Annotation_Date) AND ([Name] = @Name))";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

        gvSummary.DataSource = GetData(cmd);

        gvSummary.DataBind();

    }
```

I am getting an error that the name 'GetData' does not exist in the current context.

My using statements are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Do I need to add another statement?

Comment: Where you have defined `GetData` function? which you are using in `gvSummary.DataSource = GetData(cmd);`

Comment: There is no `GetData` in the framework. I assume that you have either missed some code from codeproject or that was just pseudo code to show you a way.

Comment: What is `GetData` supposed to be? Is that a method defined somewhere?

Comment: Wow, this is one of the good examples on Code Project :)))) Honestly I've seen some horrible stuff there

Comment: Try using `cmd.ExecuteReader()` instead of `GetData`, I think thats all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed implementing the `GetData` function. After some quick Googling I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/527201/answer.aspx) which looks like it might suit your needs.

```
private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd) 
{ 
    //string connectionString; 
    connectionString = ""; 
    connectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;Data Source=DELL-PC"; 

    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    { 
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter()) 
        { 
            cmd.Connection = con; 
            con.Open(); 
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd; 
            sda.Fill(dt); 
            return dt; 
        } 
    } 
}
```